# does aborting a thread while in 'using' block dispose used instance

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm starting a thread like this:

```
nameOfThread = new Thread(() => 
{
    //do stuff
});
nameOfThread.Start();
```

At some point inside this anonymous function I open a WinSCP session like this:

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
     //do stuff
}
```

If I abort the thread (from somewhere else) like this `nameOfThread.Abort()` while still doing stuff inside `using`, is the session disposed at the end?

Comment: Why abor the thread? Use a CancellationTokenSource and gracefully signal to the worker method that it needs to terminate

Comment: Yes, whether aborted or not the ```using``` statement still disposes properly.

Comment: Why are you using a thread directly instead of eg Task.Run?

Comment: If you have a problem and think `Thread.Abort` is part of the solution, you've found the wrong solution. Heed the warnings in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because I'm not really a savy when it comes to multithreading. but this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Mr.Howell That is why it is a comment and not an answer...

Comment: @Mr.Howell using a CancellationTokenSource is the actual answer. Don't abort the thread, they are expensive and ThreadAbortExceptions can't be caught. Use a CTS so your code can terminate gracefully

Comment: @Mr.Howell a *lot* of .NET methods accept a cancellation token too (eg database commands), which means you can cancel whatever blocking operation is running at the moment without nuking the thread

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos alright man, i will look into it 'cause i clearly don't know enough about this stuff, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it will, but [you can't be sure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831590/993547).

According to the documentation:

> When this method [`Abort`] is invoked on a thread, the system throws a `ThreadAbortException` in the thread to abort it.

And we know exceptions will still let `using` statements dispose, as they should. (Give and take a few exceptions)

On the other hand, if you can end the thread gracefully, for example with a `CancellationTokenSource`, it would be a lot nicer for your app. It will offer much more control over the actual termination of your thread and the handling of exceptions.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer and alternative. I will study multi threading more.

Comment: Keep in mind that the thread could call `ResetAbort` and prevent the effect of the `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: You'll find the inconvenient truth in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831590/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant This should no longer be true.  I remember reading this was solved in earlier versions of .NET, not sure which, where now the ```try / finally``` is nested in another ```try / finally``` with some other thread management to care for it.  Not to confuse the OP but it's a bit of behind the scenes work to make sure this doesn't happen anymore.  Looking at it, as is, without the race condition should be resolved as accurate and thread safe in current .NET releases.  I'll have to look back into it to see when this was updated.

Comment: That's an interesting tidbit that deserves better annotation, given that this does not yet happen on my machine in .NET 4.7.2 and C# v7.3.

Comment: @HansPassant So the bottom line is: don't ever dare to use `Thread.Abort()`. Your post there gives a lot of reasons to stay away from it. Thanks.

Comment: Not trying to poke you in the eye too much, but proper advice probably should resemble "no, you can't be sure".  You can make the OP feel better with "don't worry about it, the finalizer will take care of it".

Comment: @HansPassant I am not that sensitive. I appreciate your help. Updated.

Comment: @PatrickHofman can I end a task at any time I want with CancellationTokenSource though? From what I understand you put the condition in your function but what if an action takes like one hour? I want to end the task now but I have to wait one hour?

Comment: You can set a timeout to end it when it doesn't end itself. At least you give it the chance to end gracefully.

Comment: I see, for my particular situation the task is monitoring something and is basically blocked for hours, so putting timeout is a bit redundant since in 99% of the cases 1 minute wait time won't matter. I should use `Abort` in this situation I assume

Comment: @HansPassant I apologize and stand corrected.  I have dug and cannot remember when or why I thought this but I am wrong and you are correct.  The ```using``` statement does have a race condition issue when dealing with aborted threads (or any other exceptions that could occur).

Answer (score 1):

I answered you can guarantee that the `using` statement will always call `Dispose` and I **stand corrected, I was wrong**.

There **is a potential race condition with the `using` statement that doesn't guarantee disposing** and I've put together a console app illustrating this (which isn't hard or trivial).

I was correct when showing how the IL generates `using` like so:

```
var session = new Session(); //If this causes an error or abort happens during initialization then we don't enter try
//If abort is called here then we never enter try
//In either case above we may have undisposed resources initialized at this point
try
{
    //do stuff
}
finally
{
    session.Dispose();
}
```

However; note the comments where I show the race condition that may occur if aborted before entering `try`.

Here is a console app written just to prove this point. The first works as expected but if you add the commented out code `//thread.Abort()` when we initialize `R` then you will see it init but never dispose :/

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Main");

            Thread thread = null;
            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread Started");
                using (var r = new R(thread))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Using {nameof(R)}");
                }
            }));

            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();

            Console.WriteLine("End Main");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class R : IDisposable
    {
        public R(Thread thread)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Init {nameof(R)}");
            //thread.Abort();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Disposed {nameof(R)}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output with `//thread.Abort()` commented out:**

```
Start Main
Thread Started
Init R
Using R
Disposed R
End Main
```

**Output with `thread.Abort()` not commented out:**

```
Start Main
Thread Started
Init R
End Main
```

Comment: I don't think the question is about how `using` works, but how a thread abort has effect on it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You're correct. Maybe I should have explained better but I did mention that a thread, even when aborted, will always call ```finally``` and since it's basically translated into a ```try finally``` it will dispose when aborted.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I updated the answer at the bottom to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Regarding the race condition, this could be resolved by declaring `Session? session = null;` **outside** of the `try-finally`, setting `session = new();` inside the `try`, and then inside `finally` calling `session?.Dispose();`, right?