# Issue with updating my UI

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, properties

I have a `Button` and use binding to a string (`Name` property from class `Person`)

I have the following code:

```
person1.name = "Name1";
Thread.Sleep(1000);
person1.name = "Name2";
```

With Binding I only see: `Name2` after runtime.

I want to see `Name1` then after 1 second see `Name2`!

How can I realize this?
Whats the **best** method for this?

I also want to use the MVVM - Pattern if this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
person1.name = "Name1";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
     Thread.Sleep(1000);

     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
     {
         person1.name = "Name2";
     }));
});
```

[`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30680600/2946329) you can find another post about `ThreadPool` in more details.