# Invoke a Control in WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety, invoke

Hi guys i am switching one of my projects from windowsforms to WPF. So far i used this piece of code to invoke my GUI objects with data from another thread:

```
this.Invoke(new Action<NewDiagPacketArrivedEventArgs>(DoSomething), e);
```

How can I do the same thing in WPF? I found a few posts about using a dispatcher, but I could not get it to work. I would like to have a simple solution. If you know any guides on this topic I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a simple example of how using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` in WPF. Have a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316791/issue-with-updating-my-ui

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>DoStuffOnGUIThread());
```

DoStuffInGUIThread() is the method that contains the code you want to execute on the UI thread.

Comment: Is the short variant `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DoStuffOnGUIThread);` also possible?

Comment: In this case yes. But you can't add parameters and lose the advantage of closures.

Comment: If many dispatchers are invoked, they can messup UI while main thread is active, so you should add 'DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle' . It updates UI instantly.

Answer (score 2):

In Winforms, we use Control.Invoke to marshal the code from other thread to GUI thread. 
In WPF its Dispatcher.Invoke, every Dispatcher object have its own Dispatcher, on thats queue it will be marshaled.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
 {
     //Your code
 }));
```